# how to convert a grid into a 2D array

Tags: c#

For Euler problem 11, I want to convert a 20x20 grid into a 2D integer array.

The numbers in each row are separated by a space, and the rows separated with a return.

> ex:
>   34 34 34 34
>   34 34 34 34
>   34 34 34 34
>   34 34 34 34

I think the grid as shown is a string, and I want to copy/paste, then create an array; but multiple line strings don't seem to be allowed.  Would it be easier to save the grid as a file and read it into the array?
I'm not asking to solve the problem, I am only looking for help creating the array.
I found how to take each line and convert into a single-dimensional array using `.Split()`, `.Select()`, and `.ToArray()`

```
int[] rowOne = "34 34 34 34".Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

I am still a C# novice, and I'm unsure of the simplest way to convert the whole grid into a 2D array.

Comment: it's not a grid, I believe it's called "a matrix", please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: could be, it was just stated as grid in the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your grid is stored in a string called grid

```
string grid = @"34 34 34 34
            34 34 34 34
            34 34 34 34
            34 34 34 34";

var myArray = grid
    .Split('\n')
    .Select(t => t.Split(' ')
                    .Where((t1) =>
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        return int.TryParse(t1, out i);
                    })
                    .Select(int.Parse).ToArray()
            ).ToArray();
```

The code here first splits based on the newline character and then the space character.  The call to "Where" sends in an anonymous method that returns a true or false, it tries to parse to see if the value is an integer therefore selecting only the integers.

var is statically typed therefore whatever the expression returns that will be the type that myArray will be.  This actually happens at compile time not runtime.  We could just as easily say int [][] myArray = ...

**Test**

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].Length; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(myArray[i][j].ToString() + ' ');
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: I can easily cut/paste to help me move through the problem, but I always want to know what I did.  I don't know enough code yet to understand what you have here.  It works.  I don't know the function of t, t1, or the => symbol, nor how declaring the var myArray allows for a jagged array?

Comment: @user2085162  I've added some explanation of what's going on with the example.

Comment: The other area I am unfamiliar with is the use of, t =>, and t1. Is this a sort of replacement symbol?  So, t => t.split means take what is left from the newline split and then split it by spaces. When I remove the .Where () I get no result.  I would expect this to give the same result considering the grid contains all integers.  I have enough to continue with the problem. I'm just trying to understand precisely what is happening.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Multi-line strings are allowed:

```
    var multilineString = @"
34 34 34
34 34 34";
```

After this you can proceed similarly to what you've proposed:

```
string[] rows = multilineString.Split('\n');
int[] rowOne = rows[0].Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

To get 2D array:

```
string[] rows = multilineString.Split(
                  new[] {'\n'},
                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

int[][] array = rows.Select(row => row
                                   .Split(' ')
                                   .Select(int.Parse)
                                   .ToArray())
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: TO clarify then.  First I create string[] rows by splitting each line into one element.  The second part I will need to change because I want a 2d

Comment: To clarify then.  First I create string[] rows by splitting each line as one element.  I had seen the '\n' before but didn't know what it meant. Then split each element of string[] rows into separate numbers to form int[]rowOne. Although the second part I will need to change because I want a 2D array.  That should be simple with a of couple loops.  I think this has me pointed in the right direction now.   Edit- oops, mistakenly sent before finished commenting.

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide example of forming a 2D jagged array. Also "RemoveEmptyEntries" option is needed to omit the first empty line from multiLineString.